# Kubernetes REST request for data

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm fairly new to kubernetes. I've been looking at API calls to retrieve data on a particular cluster.  At the moment, I'm making three separate API calls to get this data: nodes, services & pods. Here are the calls I'm making:

```
[domain name]/api/v1/services
[domain name]/api/v1/pods
[domain name]/api/v1/nodes
```

I'm wondering if there is a single API call I can make that will get me a snapshot of the above noted?

I've snooped around kubernetes API documentation and google cloud documentation, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: What sort of data are you after? Because if it's stuff like the status of the cluster and its resources, the prometheus scraper (which is now available by default in GKE) is intended to provide that sort of cluster data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to get the native api to do this, you could implement on your own by querying for them and then watching for changes on each type and update your own data structure accordingly.